# Automatically duplicate all layers, each into its own new document

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Is there a way to create an automated action or way of duplicating multiple layers so that each layer is duplicated into its own new document. Right now I have to manually right click, and click Duplicate Layer into New Document for each layer. Is there an Action that can be created to do this? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be easily done with a simple script. Save this as a `.jsx` file to your `PS folder > Presets > Scripts`, after restarting PS it'll be available in the `File > Scripts menu`. Or simply use `File > Scripts > Browse...` to select the `.jsx` file saved anywhere.

```js
var doc = activeDocument
var layers = doc.layers;
var layer;

for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
  layer = layers[i];
  activeDocument = doc;
  doc.activeLayer = layer;
  docFromLayer(layer.name);
}

activeDocument = doc;

function docFromLayer(lname) {
    var desc240 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var ref2 = new ActionReference();
        ref2.putClass( stringIDToTypeID('document') );
    desc240.putReference( stringIDToTypeID('null'), ref2 );
    desc240.putString( stringIDToTypeID('name'), lname );
        var ref3 = new ActionReference();
        ref3.putEnumerated( stringIDToTypeID('layer'), stringIDToTypeID('ordinal'), stringIDToTypeID('targetEnum') );
    desc240.putReference( stringIDToTypeID('using'), ref3 );
    desc240.putString( stringIDToTypeID('layerName'), lname );
    executeAction( stringIDToTypeID('make'), desc240, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. that helps save a lot of time.